# Grabbing data from separate dataframe using a string reference

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

Given 2 dataframes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4',],
    'Data 1': [10, 20, 15, 25,],
    'Data 2': [12, 15, 23, 14,],
)}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4',],
    'Data 3': [16, 18, 13, 10,],
)}
```

I need to grab the data from df_2['Data 3'] while referencing df_1['Team'] as a locator, and then adding that value to a new column within df_1.

This is a very simplified version of my data, so a merge is out of the question as there are many more columns I am dealing with.

I am also trying to do this is a for loop so my locator value is currently just a string value.

```
for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    if (index % 2) == 0:
        df_1['Data 3'] = df_1[index, 'Team'].map(dict(zip(df_2['Team'], df_2['Data 3'])))
```

I know that this formula does not work as map needs a series input, but I'm hoping that it will show better of what I am trying to achieve. Uncertain of any other method to reference a dataframe like so.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the dataframes together and then apply your logic on this merged dataframe:

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='Team')
print(merged_df)

# work with merged_df afterward
# ...
```

Prints:

```
     Team  Data 1  Data 2  Data 3
0  Team 1      10      12      16
1  Team 2      20      15      18
2  Team 3      15      23      13
3  Team 4      25      14      10
```

Comment: As stated in the original problem, merge will not work as this is a very simplified version of my data.

Comment: @Link Then please post how your data looks like, to identify the problem.